# Cmd.exe output Unicode external commands

Tags: c, windows, cmd

I am trying to get unicode output from running cmd.exe commands. I see the /U switch only works for builtin commands like dir and not others like ipconfig.

If I change the name of my computer to someone like Chinese/Russian/Japanese language, and run ipconfig /all, it will display it in the console just fine. But when I use CreateProcesssW() and redirect my output to a pipe, it doesn't give me unicode back even though it is displaying it properly on the console.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    HANDLE hPipeRead, hPipeWrite;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr = { sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) };
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    if (!CreatePipe(&hPipeRead, &hPipeWrite, &saAttr, 0))
        return 0;

    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdOutput = hPipeWrite;
    si.hStdError = hPipeWrite;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };

    WCHAR works[] = L"C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /u /c dir C:\\test";
    WCHAR dont[] = L"cmd.exe /u /c ipconfig";

    BOOL fSuccess = CreateProcessW(NULL, works, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    if (!fSuccess) {
        CloseHandle(hPipeWrite);
        CloseHandle(hPipeRead);
        return 0;
    }

    BOOL bProcessEnded = FALSE;
    for (; !bProcessEnded;) {

        bProcessEnded = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 50) == WAIT_OBJECT_0;

        while (TRUE) {
            CHAR *buf = NULL;
            DWORD dwRead = 0;
            DWORD dwAvail = 0;

            if (!PeekNamedPipe(hPipeRead, NULL, 0, NULL, &dwAvail, NULL))
                break;

            if (!dwAvail)
                break;
            buf = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, dwAvail);
            if (buf == NULL) {
                return 0;
            }

            if (!ReadFile(hPipeRead, buf, dwAvail, &dwRead, NULL) || !dwRead)
                break;
            printf("%ls", buf);

        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hPipeWrite);
    CloseHandle(hPipeRead);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to get unicode back from everything ran in the cmd.exe.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp try UTF-8=65001.

Comment: I have even tried L"C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /u /c chcp 65001 & ipconfig"; and same issue

Comment: Programmers don't call user programs. See how to use wmi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmi-tasks--networking Also you can open Ipconfig in Notepad and read the what API calls it makes. So two programmers' ways.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses which is what Ipconfig uses

Comment: `ipconfig.exe` isn't Unicode-aware. For instance, `cmd.exe /u /c "chcp 65001&netsh.exe interface show interface>netshUni.txt"` produces a regular `UTF-8` file while analogous `cmd.exe /u /c "chcp 65001&ipconfig.exe>ipcUni.txt"` does not: all characters beyond  current locale are substituted with a common text-replacement character `?` (Question Mark).

Comment: @JosefZ I opened `ipconfig` in Notepad and it has these constants in it `O u t p u t E n c o d i n g     U n i c o d e   A n s i         U T F 8         U T F - 8   ÿþ  ï»¿` The last two are the Unicode byte order mark for UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Comment: You would need to change the font to see weird characters.