# How to determine the currently active code page from a Java console application on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, jna, windows-console, codepages

This is a simple Java application which displays the *default code page* on Windows:

```
package doscommand;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class DosCommand {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        InputStream in = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chcp.com").getInputStream();
        int ch;
        StringBuilder chcpResponse = new StringBuilder();
        while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
            chcpResponse.append((char) ch);
        }
        System.out.println(chcpResponse); // For example: "Active code page: 437"
    }
}
```

On my Windows 10 machine this application always displays *"Active code page: 437"* because *Cp437* is the default, and `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` starts a new `Process` when running `chcp.com`.

Is it possible to create a Java application which instead displays the *currently active code page* for the existing **Command Prompt** window in which the code is running?

I want to be able to do something like this from the **Command Prompt**:

```
chcp 1252
java -jar "D:\NB82\DosCommand\dist\DosCommand.jar" REM Shows current code page is "1252".

chcp 850
java -jar "D:\NB82\DosCommand\dist\DosCommand.jar" REM  Shows current code page is "850".
```

[How do you specify a Java file.encoding value consistent with the underlying Windows code page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1336930/2985643) asked a similar question, though in that case the OP was seeking a non-Java solution.

I'd prefer a Java-only solution, but as alternatives:

- Can this possibly be done using JNI, by calling some C/C++/C# code with access to the Windows API? The called code need only return a numeric value for the active code page.
- I'll accept an answer which persuasively argues that it can't be done.

Comment: If this were my problem, I'd search the MSDN for a C/C++ solution, and then use JNA to do it in Java. Or better yet, use C# and skip the Java step entirely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837058/cmd-exe-output-unicode-external-commands#comment96450321_54837058

Comment: chcp.com displays the current input codepage from `GetConsoleCP`. The current output codepage is `GetConsoleOutputCP`, but chcp.com doesn't use it. When setting the codepage, it sets the same value as both the input and output codepages via `SetConsoleCP` and `SetConsoleOutputCP`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Re _"use JNA to do it in Java"_ , I followed your advice. Since it worked just fine, I switched one of the tags from JNI to JNA.

Comment: @eryksun `GetConsoleCP()` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be just one line of code. [Using JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna), the value returned by the Windows API function [`GetConsoleCP()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolecp) gives the console's active code page:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;

public class JnaActiveCodePage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("" + JnaActiveCodePage.getActiveInputCodePage());
    }

    /**
     * Calls the Windows function GetConsoleCP() to get the active code page using JNA.
     * "jna.jar" and "jna-platform.jar" must be on the classpath.
     *
     * @return the code page number.
     */
    public static int getActiveInputCodePage() {
        return Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetConsoleCP();
    }
}
```

[image: chcpDemo]